# Autocovariance of a Stochastic Process

Tags: time-series, variance, stochastic-processes

Let us define a stochastic process $X_t$ as follows:

$$X_t = \sum_{i=0}^p \alpha_i \epsilon_{t-i} + \sum_{i=0}^q \beta_i \delta_{t-i}$$

where {$ε_t$} and {$δ_t$} are mutually independent normally distributed white noise processes
with finite variances $σ^2_ε$ and $σ^2_δ$ respectively. We can also assume that $p, q > 0$ and that $α_p$, $β_q$ are non-zero.

Can any braniacs help me find an expression for the autocovariance function of {$X_t$} for general values of $p, q, α_i$ and $β_i$ ? I have been trying to crack this for a while and just can't get my head around it. Any statistical wizardry would be vastly appreciated, I cannot find much about it online and I need to try and grasp this solution as soon as possible! Many, many thanks in advance.